# C# Matrix gives weird mouse coordinates

Tags: c#, matrix, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I am writing a custom control which draws polygons.
I use matrix calculations to scale and shear the polygons so that they fit the control.

I need to know if the mouse has been clicked inside one of the polygons, so I am using ray casting.

This all seems to work fine individually, however I am now encountering an issue with retrieving the mouse coordinates relative to the display matrix im using.

I use the following code:

```
// takes the graphics matrix used to draw the polygons
Matrix mx = currentMatrixTransform;            

// inverts it
mx.Invert();

// mouse position
Point[] pa = new Point[] { new Point(e.X, e.Y) };

// uses it to transform the current mouse position
mx.TransformPoints(pa);

return pa[0];
```

now this works for every other set of coordinates, by that I mean that one pair of mouse coordinates appears to give the correct values as if it has been through the matrix, but the one beside it gives a value as if it has not been through the matrix, below is an output of the mouse values received when moving down the control.

> {X=51,Y=75}
>       {X=167,Y=251}
>       {X=52,Y=77}
>       {X=166,Y=254}
>       {X=52,Y=78}
>       {X=166,Y=258}
>       {X=52,Y=79}
>       {X=166,Y=261}
>       {X=52,Y=80}
>       {X=165,Y=265}
>       {X=52,Y=81}
>       {X=165,Y=268}

if it helps the matrix used to draw the polygons is

```
Matrix trans = new Matrix();
trans.Scale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);            
trans.Shear(italicFactor, 0.0F, MatrixOrder.Append);
trans.Translate(offsetX, offsetY, MatrixOrder.Append);

e.Graphics.Transform = trans;
currentMatrixTransform = e.Graphics.Transform;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inverting your matrix each time you call it.
Matrix is a class, meaning that by performing `Invert()` on `mx`, you are also performing it on `currentMatrixTransform`.

You can either copy the matrix using `Clone()` and then invert the clone,
or you can perform `Invert()` once again after you've transformed the point `pa`.

A second invert example:

```
// takes the graphics matrix used to draw the polygons
Matrix mx = currentMatrixTransform;            

// inverts it
mx.Invert();

// mouse position
Point[] pa = new Point[] { new Point(e.X, e.Y) };

// uses it to transform the current mouse position
mx.TransformPoints(pa);

// inverts it back
max.Invert();

return pa[0];
```

A clone example:

```
// takes the graphics matrix used to draw the polygons
Matrix mx = currentMatrixTransform.Clone();

// inverts it
mx.Invert();

// mouse position
Point[] pa = new Point[] { new Point(e.X, e.Y) };

// uses it to transform the current mouse position
mx.TransformPoints(pa);

return pa[0];
```